# Sync Wi-Fi password from iOS to macOS?

Tags: macos, ios, wifi, password, keychain

I've noticed that unlike on macOS, I can't access my Wi-Fi passwords when in iOS (only browser passwords are populated in my *Settings → Safari → Passwords*).

Is it possible to sync that Wi-Fi password (or all Wi-Fi passwords, doesn't matter) somehow from my iOS device to my macOS device?

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi passwords *are* synchronised over iCloud Keychain and your iOS device will use stored AirPort network passwords when connecting to a Wi-Fi network. However, they do not show in Safari passwords since they are not for use in Safari. You cannot access stored Wi-Fi network passwords on iOS.

Comment: This particular Wi-Fi password doesn't appear in my Keychain on my Macbook—is this because I'm not running Sierra (currently on El Capitan)? Or perhaps because I haven't synced my iPhone in iTunes yet?

Comment: Have you enabled Safari's connection to iCloud on the Mac? It's in System Preferences > iCloud > Safari.